# CSS flex width issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container where I want to place some items and there is a small issue with the width of the items within the container. All of them overflow a little bit.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="body_collections">
  <div class="item_holder">
    <div class="item_image">
    </div>
    <div class="item_text_holder">
      Line 1
    </div>
    <div class="item_checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item_holder">
    <div class="item_image">
    </div>
    <div class="item_text_holder">
      Line 2
    </div>
    <div class="item_checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.body_collections {
    width:100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.item_holder {
    display:flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px 0;
}
.item_image {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.item_text_holder {
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#119911;
}
.item_checkbox {
    width:75px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#aa1111;
}
```

Here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/4frp6sbx/)

All items are 100% width but with a padding of 10px (right & left), but applying such padding make the overflow.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following css:

```
.body_collections {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Default value is `content-box`.

From [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate width and height of the elements.